# How to convert known connected component to adjacency matrix with tensor manipulations only?

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, linear-algebra, tensor

Let's say I have a N elements and I know how there are connected. 
That means there's a vector [c1, c2, ..., cn] where ci in [0...CC] CC- components count.

I want to get adjacency matrix from it.

Simple example 
input

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

output

```
1 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Is it possible to get it with linear algebra only plus some extra tensor operations from TF?

Comment: So each of these connected components is always complete (all vertices in the component are connected to each other)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done simply with a broadcasted comparison with itself:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
adjacency_matrix = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(input, 1), input), tf.int32)
print(sess.run(adjacency_matrix))
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the vector
vector = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1])

# Get the unique values in the vector
unique_values, _ = tf.unique(vector)

# Get the number of unique values (i.e. the number of components)
num_components = tf.shape(unique_values)[0]

# Create a one-hot encoding of the vector
one_hot = tf.one_hot(vector, num_components)

# Transpose the one-hot encoding
one_hot_transposed = tf.transpose(one_hot)

# Multiply the one-hot encoding by its transpose to get the adjacency matrix
adjacency_matrix = one_hot @ one_hot_transposed

# Convert the adjacency matrix to an integer tensor
adjacency_matrix = tf.cast(adjacency_matrix, tf.int32)

# Print the adjacency matrix
print(adjacency_matrix)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1]], shape=(6, 6), dtype=int32)
```